# Multiple user form input stored in an associative array using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I can't seem to make another user input values into the array. Everytime that I want to add a new form value into the array it just overrides the data. is there any other way for this code to work? without using js libraries and frameworks.
Here is my code. Thank you.

```
function array()
{
    var fName = document.getElementById('fullName').value;
    var userName = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var elmail = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var pword = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var b_day = document.getElementById('bday').value;
    var g_nder = document.getElementById('gender').value;
    var storage = [];
    var person = [];

    person[userName] = {
        "Full Name" : fName,
        "Email" : elmail,
        "Password" : pword,
        "Birthday" :  b_day,
        "Gender" : g_nder                   
    };
    storage.push(person);
    console.log(storage);           
}
```

Comment: A hashtable with only one entry makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep storage outside the function as global variable.

```js
    var storage = [];
function array()
{
    var fName = document.getElementById('fullName').value;
    var userName = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var elmail = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var pword = document.getElementById('password').value;
    var b_day = document.getElementById('bday').value;
    var g_nder = document.getElementById('gender').value;
    var person = [];

    person[userName] = {
        "Full Name" : fName,
        "Email" : elmail,
        "Password" : pword,
        "Birthday" :  b_day,
        "Gender" : g_nder                   
    };
    storage.push(person);
    console.log(storage);           
}
```

You are initilaizing storage to empty array every time